# asp.net Calendar Extendar blocked by dropdownlist controls

Tags: asp.net

My calendar extender from the Ajaxtoolkit is sometimes being blocked by nearby dropdownlist controls.

My company uses asp.net 2.0 and IE6 (I know... it sends shivers down my spine too), and at certain scroll positions the problems occurs.

When it is at correct scroll points the calendar pops up at an acceptable distance away from other controls such as dropdownlists.

I'm not sure if newer versions have this problem but is there a way to avoid it with my current versions? Preferably the popup calendar covers other controls instead of the other way around.

Upgrading is not an option.

Comment: use jQuery DatePicker[http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/] It is much more light weight and effective...

Answer (score 0):

This is a very annoying issue that I ran into as well; my company had IE 6 for the longest time.

Even if you set the z-index on the calendar item to be above that of the drop down list, it will still be blocked by the drop down lists below it (ie6 rendering issue).

The 3 options that I know of are:

1 - Use custom drop down lists

2 - overload the render for the calendar to include an iframe layer behind the calendar itself; the iframe will cover all the other elements

3 - use javascript (preferable jquery) to insert the iframe on the client side

Hopefully someone else can provide better options.

Answer (score 0):

The [bgiframe](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe) jQuery plugin was made exactly for those issues.